# Error al insertar un comentario en Unity con C # y PHP

Tags: php, c#, unity3d

Necesito ayuda con una inserción en Unity con php y c #. Mi idea es que un usuario pueda hacer uno o más comentarios, y permitir ver quién hizo dicho comentario. Para ello dispongo de dos tablas, una para usuarios y otra para opiniones.

El script PHP lo tengo así:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("config.php"); //archivo de conexion a base de datos
include("index.php");  

if(isset($_POST["newComentarioPaisaje"])){
    $comentario = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["newComentarioPaisaje"]);
    //$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["newAccountUsername"]);
//validar que no este vacio para enviar
if($comentario != "" ){
        mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO opiniones (comentario,id) VALUES ('$comentario','$id_user')");
        echo "Registro de comentario exitoso!";

            
}else{
    echo "No puede enviar un comentario vacío!";
}
}
```

Y en c # así:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class comentarioPaisaje : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public string baseUrl = "http://192.168.100.3/ramus/InsertPaisaje.php"; //server donde esta la bd/carpeta que contiene el archivo de conexion a db
    

    public InputField ComentarioPaisaje;
    public Text infopaisaje;
    
    
    public void CommentRegister()
    {
        string paiComentario = ComentarioPaisaje.text;
        StartCoroutine(RegisterNewComentario(paiComentario));

        
    }
    
    IEnumerator RegisterNewComentario(string paiComentario)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("newComentarioPaisaje", paiComentario);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(baseUrl, form))
        {
            www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
 
            if (www.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                string responseText = www.downloadHandler.text;
                Debug.Log("" + responseText); //la respuesta que se le da al usuario
                infopaisaje.text = "" + responseText; //la respuesta que se le da al usuario
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

El error que me sale en Unity:

Notice: session_start(): Ignoring session_start() because a session is already active in C:\xampp\htdocs\ramus\index.php on line 3
Error :(
Warning: Undefined variable $id_user in C:\xampp\htdocs\ramus\InsertPaisaje.php on line 13
Registro de comentario exitoso!

Answer (score 0):

El **Notice** del `session_start()` es porque estás intentando iniciar otra sesión teniendo ya una existente. Si controlas que si existe no intente realizar el `session_start()` no te saldría dicha notificación.

El **Warning** es porque la variable `$id_user` no la tienes declarada en el código de PHP, necesitas recuperar la información de la base de datos al igual que `$comentario`.